# Deformation of Display on Zink's paper

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, p-divisible-group-schemes, dieudonne-modules

I am going to compute some intersection numbers on certain RZ spaces and therefore need to fully understand the deformation of $p$-divisible groups. This can be understood as deformation of displays, where displays are generalized notions of Dieudonné modules.

The question is about the paper

- Thomas Zink, *A Dieudonné Theory for p-Divisible Groups*, in: Class Field Theory – Its Centenary and Prospect, K. Miyake, ed. (Tokyo: Mathematical Society of Japan, 2001), 139-160, doi:[10.2969/aspm/03010139](https://doi.org/10.2969/aspm/03010139), [author pdf](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Ezink/CFTpaper.pdf).

On page 8, Theorem 4, it says it follows immediately from Theorem 3, which I didn't see why and confusing for a long time. Let me put my question clear by writing the following.

The definition of a display is the following

**Definition** A *Dieudonne display* over $R$ is a quadruple $(P, Q, F, V^{−1})$, where $P$ is a finitely generated free $\widehat{W}(R)$-module, $Q\subset P$ is a submodule and $F$ and $V^{−1}$ are $F$-linear maps
$$
F \colon P \longrightarrow  P,\qquad V^{ −1}: Q \longrightarrow P.
$$
The following properties are required to be satisfied:

- $\widehat{I}_RP \subset Q \subset P$ and $P/Q$ is a free $R$-module.
- $V^{−1}\colon Q\longrightarrow P$ is an $F$-linear epimorphism.
- For any $x \in P$ and $w \in \widehat{W} (R)$, we have
  $$
  V^{−1}(\;^Vwx) = wF x.
  $$

The above was the definition of the display, one can look at the reference for more details, here $\widehat W(R)$ is a subring of the Witt vectors $W(R)$ and $\widehat{I_R}$ is the kernel of the first ghost map $\widehat W(R)\longrightarrow R$.

I wish to understand the deformation of the display, the set up is a surjective ring homomorphism
$$
S\longrightarrow R
$$
with ideal $\mathfrak a$. We assume $p$ is nilpotent in $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak a$ has equipped with a $p$-divided power structure. Zink has proved the following Theorem

**Theorem 3** Let us consider a pd-thickening $S\longrightarrow R$ as above. Let
$$
\mathcal P_i =(P_i, Q_i, F, V^{−1})
$$
for $i = 1, 2$ be Dieudonne displays over $S$. Let
$$
\overline{\mathcal P_i }=(\overline{P_i}, \overline{Q_i}, F, V^{−1})=P_{i,R}
$$
be the reductions over $R$. Assume we are given a
morphism of Dieudonne displays $u \colon \overline{\mathcal P_1} \to \overline{\mathcal P_2}$. Then there exists a unique
morphism of quadruples
$$
u \colon (P_1, \widehat Q_1, F, V^{−1})\longrightarrow (P_2, \widehat Q_2, F, V^{−1}),
$$
which lifts the morphism $u$.

Here $\widehat Q_i$ is the preimage of $\overline{Q_i}$ in the map $P_i\longrightarrow \overline{P_i}$

Then Zink just said that **Theorem 4** in the paper and says it follows immediately from **Theorem 3**.

Let me say an equivalent form of **Theorem 4**

**Equivalent of Theorem 4** Let
$$
\overline{\mathcal P }=(\overline{P}, \overline{Q}, F, V^{−1})
$$
be a display over $R$. And let $P$ be the base change of $\overline {P}$ from $\widehat{W}(R)$ to $\widehat{W}(S)$. For any
$$
L\subset P/\widehat I_S P
$$
such that it reduces to $\overline Q\subset \overline P/\widehat I_R P$. Let $Q_L$ be the preimage of $L$ via the map $P\longrightarrow P/\widehat I_S P$.  Then there exists a unique display up to (*)-isomorphisms
$$
\mathcal P = (P,Q_L,F,V^{-1})
$$
such that it reduces to the display $\overline{\mathcal P}$ in $R$. Here a (*)-isomorphism means it reduces to identity map in $R$.

Zink says it follows immediately from **Theorem 3**, which I feel not obvious at all.

I am interested in **Theorem 4**, it is saying to lift a display is the same as lifting a Hodge filtration. But it is extremely confusing because Zink did not mention why any lifting of a Hodge filtration there exists a display corresponds to it? Zink also did not explain why the display corresponding to a lifting of Hodge filtration is unique. Both of the questions is not obvious from **Theorem 3**. I guess uniqueness part might come from **Theorem 3**.